# squeeze theorem and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}, r>0$ and $J=[a,a+r)$, and let $f,g,h: J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with

\begin{align}
f(x)\leq h(x)\leq g(x)
\end{align}

for all $x\in J$. Suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable in $a$, and $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f'(a)=g'(a)$. Prove that $h$ is differentiable in $a$ and $h'(a)=f'(a)$

I used the squeeze theorem to show that $f(a)=h(a)=g(a)$. I get stuck at the part where I have to show that $h$ is differentiable in $a$

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Subtract $f(a) = h(a) = g(a)$ and then divide by $x-a > 0$. You get

$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \leq \frac{h(x)-h(a)}{x-a} \leq \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$

Finally, apply squeeze theorem again.

If you where working on an open interval, then it may happen that $x-a < 0$. But then the reverse inequality will hold.

$\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a} \leq \frac{h(x)-h(a)}{x-a} \leq \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

Comment: Your inequalities hold only if $x-a>0$.

Comment: The inequality holds in the defined interval

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really helpful!